# How do I populate empty cells with values equal to non-empty cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, I have the following column

```
A
(empty)
(empty)
B
(empty)
C
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
```

I want to populate the empty cells with the non-empty values before the empty stacks like the following:

```
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
C
```

I prefer to accomplish this as simple as possible, so I avoid using VBA unless macro is very simple such that I can easily teach others how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually select the range of cells and then:

<kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> and then touch <kbd>Special...</kbd> and select *Blanks*

Then touch <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>UP ARROW</kbd> and finish with <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: The question might already exists, but this answer is easier to understand!